# How to grab a string of text from text file before and after the matching pattern?

Tags: string, perl

I have a text file called `mytext.txt`. I want to grab the sting of text from in this file before and after the string `Query:` of the same line.

mytext.txt:

```
   # P-value cutoff: 1
    # Category cutoff: 4
    # Output Format: Pretty
    ---------------------------------------------------

    5' UGGGAGGAUGGGAUGGGAAAG 3' Transcript: Supercontig_2.10_1111019:1499-1519 Slice Site:1510
       ||oo||o| o|o|| o|||||
    3' ACUUUCUUUUCUUAAUCUUUC 5' Query: Seq_2171_593

    SiteID: Supercontig_2.10_1111019:1510
    MFE of perfect match: -26.00
    MFE of this site: -18.70
    MFEratio: 0.719230769230769
---------------------------------------------------

5' GUUUGGAAAGGCGGUUACGGGG 3' Transcript: Supercontig_2.10_1257006:252-273 Slice Site:264
   |oo||||||o||||||  o|oo
3' CGGACCUUUUCGCCAAGAUCUU 5' Query: Seq_5744_249

SiteID: Supercontig_2.10_1257006:264
```

here is my code that I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use Modern::Perl;


my $word = "Query";

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(INPUT_FILE, $filename);
while (<INPUT_FILE>) {
chomp;
#for my $word (@words) {
        my ($before, $after) = $_ =~ /(\S+)(?:\t\Q$word\E\t)(\S+)/i;
        say "word: $word\tbefore: $before\tafter: $after";
#    }
}
```

Result I want:

```
3' ACUUUCUUUUCUUAAUCUUUC 5'   Seq_2171_593
3' CGGACCUUUUCGCCAAGAUCUU 5'  Seq_5744_249
```

PS. I can do this using various other methods such as unix one liners, but I am learning perl and want to get this done in perl. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `\S` [character class](https://perldoc.pl/perlrebackslash#Character-classes) matches anything other than whitespace characters. You want everything other than newline characters, which is just `.`. Your word has a `:` after it which your regex needs to account for. And finally the `\t` will match only a tab character, are there actual tab characters before and after the word you're looking for?

```
my ($before, $after) = m/(.+)(?:\t\Q$word\E:\t)(.+)/i;
```

As a side note, the `readline` operator (`<>`/`<<>>`) uses the special [ARGV](https://perldoc.pl/variables/ARGV) filehandle by default which will open and read from each file specified as arguments, so you don't have to get the filename from `@ARGV` and open it yourself, you can just do:

```
while (<<>>) { ... }
```

(If your Perl is older than 5.22 you have to use `while (<>)` which is less safe because it allows executing commands passed as arguments; for similar reasons you should [always use three-arg open](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Freenode::OpenArgs) when opening files yourself.)

Comment: Your solution gives me error:word: Query: `before: after: Use of uninitialized value $before in concatenation (.) or string at my_perl_script.pl line 17, <INPUT_FILE> line 19559. Use of uninitialized value $after in concatenation (.) or string at my_perl_script.pl line 17, <INPUT_FILE> line 19559.`

Comment: It sounds like you've put that line of code in a string by accident.